# Complex logic on a ElementCriteriaModel parameter?

Tags: elementcriteriamodel

How would you combine multiple logical expressions on a ElementCriteriaModel parameter?
You could query twice and then merge the two returned arrays of entry models,
but that probably wouldn't allow me to later use the [`{% paginate %}`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/paginate) tag or methods like [`getNext()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#getNext).

Here's an example where I'd like to filter events starting in calender week 32 or 34:

```
{% set dateParamCw32 = 'and, >= 2014-08-04 00:00:00, < 2014-08-10 23:59:59' %}
{% set dateParamCw34 = 'and, >= 2014-08-18 00:00:00, < 2014-08-24 23:59:59' %}

{% set startDateParam = 'date range cw32 OR cw34' %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.section('events').startDate(startDateParam) %}
```

Comment: This is a complicated answer and would need to be answered by Pixel & Tonic. Each condition goes through Craft's condition processor and then through Yii's condition processor before finalizing as a query. There's a lot of moving parts, and they would know those parts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For most cases you can find a workaround to combine such conditions by making use of entry IDs.

In this example query for each time range condition separately and use the `ids()` method to "collect" your entries. All matching IDs are then passed to the `id` parameter of a final ElementCriteriaModel, that you can also use for Pagination etc.:

```
{% set dateParamCw32 = 'and, >= 2014-08-04 00:00:00, < 2014-08-10 23:59:59' %}
{% set dateParamCw34 = 'and, >= 2014-08-18 00:00:00, < 2014-08-24 23:59:59' %}

{% set entriesCw32Ids = craft.entries.section('events').startDate(dateParamCw32).ids() %}
{% set entriesCw34Ids = craft.entries.section('events').startDate(dateParamCw34).ids() %}

{% set idParam = [] %}
{% set idParam = idParam|merge(entriesCw32Ids) %}
{% set idParam = idParam|merge(entriesCw34Ids) %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.id(idParam) %}
```