# Can I have multiple comparisons within a single criteria parameter?

Tags: elementcriteriamodel

[The Craft site shows an example using a single comparison](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#parameter-value-syntax)

Building upon this example from that page:

`craft.entries.width('>= 100')`

Can I do something similar but where 'width' is ALSO less than or equal to 200?

Conceptually:

`craft.entries.width('>= 100 && <= 200')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine multiple criteria like so:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.width('and, >= 100, <= 200') %}
```

but what you can't do is to combine multiple statements to build more complex criteria:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.width('and, >= 100, <= 200' or '>= 500') %}
```

in your case this wouldn't make much sense. But see my still unanswered question on this topic for another example: ["Complex logic on a ElementCriteriaModel parameter?"](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/1948/125)

Answer (score 2):

You can use some basic logic with `and` or `or` like this:

```
craft.entries.width('and, >= 100, <= 200')
```