# Search for entries where a field value is between multiple ranges of numbers

Tags: elementcriteriamodel

I currently have this working for a single range of numbers, but I can’t figure it out for multiple ranges. I currently have it set up like this for one range, and it works. `myFieldHandle: ['and', '> 0', '< 10']`.

Comment: Providing some of your code will help others more easily answer your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Complex logic on a ElementCriteriaModel parameter?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1948/complex-logic-on-a-elementcriteriamodel-parameter)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you can do this in the same query but you can use two queries, one for each range, and then merge them, something like this:

```
{% set range1 = craft.entries({myFieldHandle: ['and', '> 0', '< 10']}) %}
{% set range2 = craft.entries({myFieldHandle: ['and', '> 20', '< 30']}) %}
{% set entries = range1 |merge(range2) %}
```

Comment: This is an excellent way to do it. You should query for the `ids`, and then merge those, and then query by id.